# Serverless architecture - Azure functions @edge

Tags: azure, aws-lambda, azure-functions, serverless

We have below technical stack in our application

- Angular 7
- Asp.net core 2.2
- Sql server
- Images

To go for serverless architecture on Azure, we have map as follows

- Angular 7 - Blob (as it is static)
- Asp.net core 2.2 - Azure functions
- SQL server - SQL as a service
- Images - Blob

Now how to handle Azure functions@Edge ?

Do we have alike Lambda@Edge in AWS?

Comment: Check [Serverless to the Max: Doing Big Things for Small Dollars with Cloudflare Workers and Azure Functions](https://www.troyhunt.com/serverless-to-the-max-doing-big-things-for-small-dollars-with-cloudflare-workers-and-azure-functions/) . by Troy Hunt. He explains how he uses CloudFlare Worrkers with Azure functions to provide edge processing for `haveibeenpwnd` while paying out of his pocket. Cloudflare is more advanced and faster than Lambda@Edge, at least for now.

Comment: Different cloud providers have different strengths. Even "buying" from the same provider doesn't mean you'll have a smoother or cheaper experience. You should check the pros/cons and cost of each solution and architecture. Bear in mind that *javascript* functions have better startup time than .NET Core so you may have to write some functions in Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there's no equivalent Azure service right now. In fact, back in October 2018, the comparison between Lambda@Edge and Azure IoT Edge [was removed](https://github.com/mspnp/architecture-center/issues/831) from the [Services Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/aws-professional/services) page.

The equivalent right now would be to use CloudFlare Workers combined with Azure Functions. Troy Hunt explains how he did just that to scale [Have I Been Pwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/) in [Serverless to the Max: Doing Big Things for Small Dollars with Cloudflare Workers and Azure Functions](https://www.troyhunt.com/serverless-to-the-max-doing-big-things-for-small-dollars-with-cloudflare-workers-and-azure-functions/). The site has a *lot* of traffic and Troy Hunt pays for it out of his own pocket. Workers on the edge means that Have I Been Pwned doesn't have to hit Blob storage in most cases.

Right now this may be a very good choice. Cloudflare Workers are [faster](https://blog.cloudflare.com/serverless-performance-comparison-workers-lambda/?hn) than Lambda@Edge *at this point* and CloudFlare offers very good caching, proxying and DDOS protection services. You'll have to consider startup time too. Javascript functions can start faster than Java or .NET Core functions, which means they can handle cold starts and request bursts better.

All of this will certainly change in the future. Functions on the edge is a lucrative market. Lambda@Edge will definitely get faster. Azure may add its own service or cooperate with CloudFlare.

Comment: It’s 2022. Still hoping for #Azure to make a move. They have highest density of data centers worldwide compared to AWS and GCP as of now. Why not adding Functions@Edge to the portfolio? 

Right now, the only way to go edge on Azure is to automate the deployment of Azure Functions hosts in every region by yourself.

Comment: @Lukaesch are you sure? There are a gazillion of Azure offerings now, with Azure Edge even running on Lenovo docking stations. No idea why. IoT Edge is back in the Services comparison anyway. There could be other services with more obscure names that actually do the job

Answer (score 1):

Two questions: 
1. Why not use any CDN on azure in order to server your static files? Blob storage is not for static content but usually for user related binaries.
2. Why not use the [[Azure app service][1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to host your .net core api (if it is an api)?

You can find documentation on how to use the functions with .net core [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/09/25/develop-azure-functions-on-any-platform/)

Comment: This should be a comment. In any case *serverless* stacks like AWS Lambdas/Azure Functions are better in many scenarios than a hosted service like an Azure App Service - they scale better and cost less when not used. Blob storage *is* used for static files, especially for static sites. Finally, the CDN has to get the files from somewhere and that's usually Blob storage.

Comment: Thanks AK for quick response.

Yes, files will be stored in blob and will be served from CDN

So when i was saying serverless architecture, i was talking about this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/overview/serverless-computing/#explore-azure-serverless-apps

I do not have to pay for actual time your code is running

Comment: Check how [Troy Hunt](https://www.troyhunt.com/i-wanna-go-fast-why-searching-through-500m-pwned-passwords-is-so-quick/) used Azure Blob storage to get 56ms response for password searches.

Comment: Also [Serverless to the Max: Doing Big Things for Small Dollars with Cloudflare Workers and Azure Functions](https://www.troyhunt.com/serverless-to-the-max-doing-big-things-for-small-dollars-with-cloudflare-workers-and-azure-functions/). Serverless on the edge can improve performance and reduce costs immensely. The local MS salesmen won't be that happy though

Comment: Thanks PK for your quick response, yes, this is what i was talking about

How @Edge is managed with Azure Functions ?

Comment: @PK, so you mean we can achieve with Cloudflare which is 3rd party ?